# Fetch Country code and mobile number from contact

Tags: android, libphonenumber

I'm trying to get phone number from contact and if it has country code, separate it from mobile number. We've two fields CountryCode and MobileNumber. 
There are 4 different scenarios i like to handle

- (+CountryCode)(MobileNumber) : I like to get both
- (CountryCode)(MobileNumber)  : I like to get both
- (0)(MobileNumber)            : I like to get MobileNumber
- (MobileNumber)               : I like to get MobileNumber

I've tried using [Google libphonenumber](https://github.com/google/libphonenumber), but it's failing in 4th scenario.

For example,In case if my contact is like this 8109112345. I'll get country code as 81 and mobileNumber as 09112345 because Country code of Japan is +81.

This is how i'm using the library.

```
int countryCode = phoneNumberUtil.extractCountryCode(new StringBuilder(contact), new StringBuilder(""));
String regionCode = phoneNumberUtil.getRegionCodeForCountryCode(countryCode);
final Phonenumber.PhoneNumber phoneNumber = util.parse(contact, regionCode);
```

Is there any other library which does this or any other way this can be achieved ?

Comment: What you are getting from 4th option?

Comment: @PankajKumar with respect to the example in question, I'm getting country code as 81 and mobile number as 09112345.

Comment: And what is expected? Do you mean you should get "8109112345" as mobile number.

Comment: Yes. The library check if the first 3 numbers matches with the list of Country Code. If it does, it'll consider first match as country code. In this case 81 for Japan.